# How to put timer in if condition?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

First thing this is not my code I just edit to make new things
this is the code I edited, i want my rocket to drop down and stay for maybe 1 sec until it lunch. I did an animation on rocket to drop for 24 frame.

This code makes my rocket drop because of animation but it was moving when it drop.

```
public class RocketMss extends MovieClip {

    var rocketSpeed:Number;
    var rocketTimer:Timer;
    var timing:Number;

     function RocketMss() {

        timing = 0;
        rocketSpeed = 12;
        addEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
    }

    function enterFrame(e:Event){

        rocketTimer = new Timer(100);
        timing = 1;
        if(timing == 1){
            this.x += rocketSpeed;
            timing = 0;
            if((this.currentFrame == this.totalFrames) && this.x > 640){
                removeEventListener("enterFrame", enterFrame);
                stage.removeChild(this);
            }
        }


    }
```

thank you of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could delay the enter frame start by using a `Timer` or a `setTimeout`. For example:

```
function RocketMss() {
    setTimeout(startMoving, 1000);
}

function startMoving():void {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
}

function enterFrame(e:Event):void {
    this.x += rocketSpeed;
    if(this.x > 640){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrame);
        stage.removeChild(this);
    }
}
```

Another way to do it is to simply call the `startMoving` function from the timeline from a frame after the "drop" animation has finished.

Another way would be to rely on a frame label, and from your `enterFrame` handler you just check [`currentLabel`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#currentLabel) before moving.